# How to creat multiple columns of dummies for intervals in R

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals, cut

```
data$Distance_100<-0
data$Distance_100[data$Distance<100]<-1

data$Distance_200<-0
data$Distance_200[data$Distance>=101&data$Distance<200]<-1

data$Distance_300<-0
data$Distance_300[data$Distance>=201&data$Distance<300]<-1

data$Distance_400<-0
data$Distance_400[data$Distance>=301&data$Distance<400]<-1

data$Distance_500<-0
data$Distance_500[data$Distance>=401&data$Distance<500]<-1
```

The outcome must be multiple columns. This code creat just one column `data$DistanceCut5 = cut(data$Distance, breaks=c(0,100,200,300,400,500))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` will create a single column, but if you want 1 column for each cut level you could do something like this:

## Example

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Code

```
# Vector with a sequence from 0 to 500 by 100
seq_0_500 <- seq(0,500,100)

# Example data.frame
tibble(
  # Variable distance = sequence from 1 to 500 by 1
  distance = 1:500
) %>% 
  mutate(
    #Create a categoric variable by 100: `(0,100]` `(100,200]` `(200,300]` `(300,400]` `(400,500]`
    distance_cut = cut(distance,seq_0_500, labels = paste0("Distance_",seq_0_500[-1])),
    #Auxiliar variable
    aux = 1
    ) %>% 
  # Pivot data to make one column for each cut level
  pivot_wider(names_from = distance_cut,values_from = aux) %>% 
  # Replace every NA for 0
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 500 x 6
   distance Distance_100 Distance_200 Distance_300 Distance_400 Distance_500
      <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1        1            1            0            0            0            0
 2        2            1            0            0            0            0
 3        3            1            0            0            0            0
 4        4            1            0            0            0            0
 5        5            1            0            0            0            0
 6        6            1            0            0            0            0
 7        7            1            0            0            0            0
 8        8            1            0            0            0            0
 9        9            1            0            0            0            0
10       10            1            0            0            0            0
# ... with 490 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. First provide reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
var <- round(runif(50, 0, 500))
dummy <- cut(var, breaks=c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500))
table(dummy)
# dummy
#   (0,100] (100,200] (200,300] (300,400] (400,500] 
#         7         6         9        10        18
```

Now create columns for each value:

```
dumvar <-table(row(as.matrix(dummy)), dummy)
head(dumvar); tail(dumvar)
#    dummy
#     (0,100] (100,200] (200,300] (300,400] (400,500]
#   1       0         0         0         0         1
#   2       0         0         0         0         1
#   3       0         1         0         0         0
#   4       0         0         0         0         1
#   5       0         0         0         1         0
#   6       0         0         1         0         0
#     dummy
#      (0,100] (100,200] (200,300] (300,400] (400,500]
#   45       0         0         1         0         0
#   46       0         0         0         0         1
#   47       0         0         0         0         1
#   48       0         0         0         1         0
#   49       0         0         0         0         1
#   50       0         0         0         1         0
```

If you want to rename the columns:

```
dimnames(dumvar)$dummy <- paste0("Distance_", seq(100, 500, by=100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice approach: first cut your data, then use `model.matrix()` to create dummy variables.

```r
data <- data.frame(Distance = runif(20, 0, 500))
DistanceCut5 = cut(data$Distance, breaks=c(0,100,200,300,400,500))
dummies <- model.matrix(~ DistanceCut5 + 0) # + 0 so we don't have a column of 1s
data <- cbind(data, dummies)
```

Make sure you don't have any NAs in `DistanceCut5`. Otherwise you'll get too few rows in your matrix of dummies.